# Move button in the left middle screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to move a button in the middle of the left screen but when I change anything the entire things move. like for example, I am using cards when I move the button down the cards move too which I don't want.

Sandbox link : [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-resonance-vuecm?file=/src/App.vue)

I just want to display a button with expanding effect when hover over it, but it should stick to the left side of the UI and in the middle.

**Current:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

Comment: I'm not real familiar with vue, but if you put the equivalent of this for the button you'll get your desired effect. `style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:0;transform:translateY(-50%)"`

Answer (score 0):

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-cache-nwl0c?file=/App.vue

I added the expandable button for you and placed it where you wanted without moving it in the html. I did this by adjusting its **margin-bottom**.
For the animation on hover for the button I used the css property transition which you can read about a little [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) if you are interested in learning more. I also added the id of runAll to the button.

Code:

```
<style>
#runAll {
  width: 100px;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-in;
}

#runAll:hover {
  width: 500px;
}
</style>
<template>
  <div>
    <b-button id="runAll" class="runAll" style="margin-bottom: -425px">Run All</b-button>
    <b-card-group deck>
      <b-card border-variant="info" header="Info" align="center">
        <b-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</b-card-text>
      </b-card>

      <b-card
        border-variant="warning"
        header="Warning"
        header-bg-variant="transparent"
        align="center"
      >
        <b-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</b-card-text>
      </b-card>

      <b-card
        border-variant="danger"
        header="Danger"
        header-border-variant="danger"
        header-text-variant="danger"
        align="center"
      >
        <b-card-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</b-card-text>
      </b-card>
    </b-card-group>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```